# Problem with validation in express + express-validator

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, validation

I have a post creation request handler. Incoming data is verified using an express-validator.
But I have a problem: when I send a request with empty parameters, not all validations are processed, and instead of 5 error messages, I receive only 2, what could I have missed?

**validation:**

```
export const postValidation = [
  body("title", "The title must be more than 5 characters").isString().isLength({
    min: 5,
    max: 100,
  }),
  body("tags", "Specify tags").exists().isArray().notEmpty(),
  body("text", "Provide detailed information about your project")
    .isString()
    .isLength({
      min: 20,
      max: 5000,
    }),
  body("needs", "Indicate who you need").exists().isArray().notEmpty(),
  body("socials", "Provide contact information to contact you")
    .exists()
    .isArray()
    .notEmpty(),
];
```

**CreatePost:**

```
export const createProject = async (req: AuthRequest, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json(errors.array());
    }

    const query = `INSERT INTO projects (title, tags, text, needs, socials, creator_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)`;
    const values = [
      req.body.title,
      req.body.tags,
      req.body.text,
      req.body.needs,
      req.body.socials,
      req.userId,
    ];

    const result = await pool.query(query, values);

    res.json({ success: true, message: "Success" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Error",
    });
  }
};
```

I tried to rewrite the validation; previously I used isLength() to check if the array was full.